# What is the difference between The past tense of be and Simple present tense?

Tags: grammar

for example
What is the difference between
I did play
and
I played

Comment: Simple Present is ***I play***. Both your examples are Past Tense, where the ***do-support*** version normally conveys *emphasis* (often, specifically, *refutation* - when someone else said that you *didn't* do something).

Comment: Your title asks about "the past tense of be and simple present tense", while your question asks about "I did play and I played". There is a major disconnect.

Comment: This question is a mess because it makes no sense. Sorry. You mean: What is the difference between the emphatic did play and played, the simple past.

Answer (score 2):

```
1.I did play.
```

Did is the past form of do. You use that for emphasis as in "I don’t do much sport now, but I did play football when I was younger."

```
2. I played..
```

Basic version in describing a past action.

Comment: From an American English perspective, I don't recall ever using "much sport" in a sentence. I would say "I don't do many sports now" or I don't play many sports now." Would your rewording of #1 be British English?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for the comment. I should have mentioned that I took that example from Michael Swan's Practical English Usage who is a British writer. And I'm not a native British speaker. :)